# Angular mat-table,cannot retrieve any infos driectly from the table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material-table

Please help me with this!. I have a mat-table with 5 columns and more rows. Rows are added by reading my own api. On last row I have a button which open a modal. I want to populate that modal with data from the row I clicked on .Ex: if I click on the first row it opens a modal with 5 labels in witch I take values from each column for the row I clicked on .

```
<div class="uc-modal" *ngIf="showModal ===1">
    <div class="uc-m-content">
        <div class="uc-m-header">
            <mat-icon (click)="close()" class="h4alg">close</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="uc-m-body">
            <h4>Maintenance info</h4>
            <label>column1</label>                    //take data from column 1 row I clicked on
            <label>column2</label>
            <label>column3</label>
            <label>column4</label>
            <label>column5</label>
        </div>
        <div class="uc-m-footer">
            <button mat-flat-button color="accent" (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
            <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or to put it more simple how i read any value from any cell in a variable in my component .ts file.  Eg: I want to read value of column 2 row 3.

Comment: You didn't post your `mat-table` code.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wp7gj9-erosv7?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html I will provide a stackblitz